# why don't almost all databases implement row cache?

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, innodb

I noticed that almost all database don't implement row cache internally. I ask this question because I find someone add [row-cache patch for innodb](http://code.google.com/p/row-cache-for-innodb/). At least, it has one advantage beyond performance gain, i.e. it is transparent for the client.

Is there any difficult technical reason which prevent doing so, or just because it's useful for very specific access pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Quite frankly, if you're getting the same version of the same row multiple times, you're doing it wrong. Data should be cached, as a general rule, if it's unlikely to change and needs to be accessed multiple times. Given this rule, if caching a DB row on the server side ever helps, it means you're making too many round trips to the database for the data you're interested in. You should instead be caching it *client-side* to cut down on the round trips. If the data changes often and so you need to access it often, caching *still* won't help because the cached data is out of date and the query must be re-executed. Only getting the data that's different from the cached data doesn't help; you have to figure out what's different and you're still making a query of the DB.

On top of that, most databases are designed for high-concurrency performance. Caching one guy's massive result set is going to eat into resources available for the next guy's massive result set and so on. In a high-user-count scenario, building a cache would likely simply result in the cached data being thrown away to make room for more cached data; it wouldn't be able to stick around long enough to be of use.

Comment: It seems that you are talking about application cache, while i am talking about row-cache which is similar with memcache, the difference between them is row-cache should be protected by transaction.

Comment: I am not talking about application cache. Row-caching is when the RDBMS loads and stores row data in memory for faster access. The problems are exactly as I said; if you are requesting the same data so often that a cache would improve performance, you would improve performance by many orders of magnitude more simply by reducing query frequency. The single scenario in which row-caching helps when client-side caching wouldn't is when multiple independent clients run the same query for the same data; this prevents the DBMS having to re-retrieve it from disk every time.

Comment: It's not exactly a fringe need, but it is highly specialized.